# Spring, Spring Security, JPA, MySQL, Hibernate Configuration

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-security

I am working on a project that uses spring security, hibernate, JPA, mySQL...I am trying to get my signup, login, and logout working for this project and none of the user input is being stored in the database, and and cannot figure this out to save my life. I have tried pretty much everything I can think of and I've come to the conclusion that I must be missing some fundamental information about how all of this actually works. It is unclear to me if I am supposed to create the tables, and insert initial data into them before i run the project, or if the tables are created and configured by the code below. Does there need to be an inital creation of the table in my database? If so...what is the proper way to create these tables so that user input will be stored in the database? I am especially confused by the @JoinTable users-role.

```
package com.stephanie.mycapec.models;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    public User() {
    }
    public User(Long id, String email, String password, String fullname, boolean enabled){
        this.id = id;
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
        this.fullname=fullname;
        this.enabled=enabled;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String fullname;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))

    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("User[id=%d, email='%s', password='%s', name='%s'" );
    }


}
```

Would i also need to initialize a table for users_roles in my database? Or is the schema table created by the @JoinTable?

This is what my console looks like when I run the program, it seems it is having some issue with the repository but i am not sure how to fix this either.

```
2020-04-22 22:30:23.260  INFO 25452 --- [           main] com.stephanie.mycapec.MyCapecApp         : Starting MyCapecApp on DESKTOP-4G0GSBA with PID 25452 (C:\Users\Stephanie\My-Capec\build\classes\java\main started by Stephanie in C:\Users\Stephanie\My-Capec)
2020-04-22 22:30:23.263  INFO 25452 --- [           main] com.stephanie.mycapec.MyCapecApp         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/C:/Users/Stephanie/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.9/4222eafca660d01a44682c3fe4c629005728973/groovy-2.5.9.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-04-22 22:30:23.887  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-04-22 22:30:23.887  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-22 22:30:23.919  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.stephanie.mycapec.repositories.ApdbRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-04-22 22:30:23.920  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.stephanie.mycapec.repositories.RoleRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-04-22 22:30:23.921  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.stephanie.mycapec.repositories.UseCaseRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-04-22 22:30:23.922  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.stephanie.mycapec.repositories.UserRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-04-22 22:30:23.922  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2020-04-22 22:30:23.929  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-04-22 22:30:23.929  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-22 22:30:23.960  INFO 25452 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 28ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-04-22 22:30:24.217  INFO 25452 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-04-22 22:30:24.388  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-22 22:30:24.394  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-22 22:30:24.394  INFO 25452 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-04-22 22:30:24.523  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-22 22:30:24.523  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1115 ms
2020-04-22 22:30:24.685  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-04-22 22:30:24.742  INFO 25452 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
2020-04-22 22:30:24.832  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-04-22 22:30:24.906  INFO 25452 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-22 22:30:25.208  INFO 25452 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-22 22:30:25.218  INFO 25452 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Hibernate: alter table role_users add constraint FKipeyaf3dve9njdrl1t23ndidv foreign key (users_id) references user (id)
Hibernate: alter table role_users add constraint FKele6ufqrv6w1uoxqw6h1vkki0 foreign key (role_id) references role (id)
Hibernate: alter table users_roles add constraint FKt4v0rrweyk393bdgt107vdx0x foreign key (role_id) references role (id)
Hibernate: alter table users_roles add constraint FKgd3iendaoyh04b95ykqise6qh foreign key (user_id) references user (id)
2020-04-22 22:30:25.927  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-04-22 22:30:25.933  INFO 25452 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-22 22:30:25.980  WARN 25452 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-04-22 22:30:26.376  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/resources/**'], []
2020-04-22 22:30:26.376  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/static/**'], []
2020-04-22 22:30:26.376  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/css/**'], []
2020-04-22 22:30:26.376  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/js/**'], []
2020-04-22 22:30:26.376  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/images/**'], []
2020-04-22 22:30:26.399  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1238a074, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6e12f38c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5a4e492c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@240291d9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@640a6d4b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5a9baba8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1b79df53, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@35b58254, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@26a202ae, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@534d0cfa, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@49c4118b]
2020-04-22 22:30:26.517  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-22 22:30:26.887  INFO 25452 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-22 22:30:26.889  INFO 25452 --- [           main] com.stephanie.mycapec.MyCapecApp         : Started MyCapecApp in 3.887 seconds (JVM running for 4.6)
Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_1_, role0_.role as role2_1_ from role role0_ where role0_.role=?
Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_1_, role0_.role as role2_1_ from role role0_ where role0_.role=?
2020-04-22 22:30:32.835  INFO 25452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-22 22:30:32.835  INFO 25452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-22 22:30:32.842  INFO 25452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
2020-04-22 22:30:33.050  WARN 25452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [175] milliseconds.
2020-04-22 22:30:33.421  WARN 25452 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] n.n.u.t.expressions.ExpressionProcessor  : Fragment expression "default" is being wrapped as a Thymeleaf 3 fragment expression (~{...}) for backwards compatibility purposes.  This wrapping will be dropped in the next major version of the expression processor, so please rewrite as a Thymeleaf 3 fragment expression to future-proof your code.  See https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451 for more information.
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_4_, user0_.email as email2_4_, user0_.enabled as enabled3_4_, user0_.fullname as fullname4_4_, user0_.password as password5_4_ from user user0_ where user0_.email=?
```

also here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login?useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = uber
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

If anyone can please help me figure out how to get user input stored in the database to get my login and and authentication working in my spring project i would be eternally grateful.

EDIT
As requested, here is my role entity

```
package com.stephanie.mycapec.models;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity= User.class)
    //@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<User> users;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide complete code for your user entity? as well as your role entity? Also how are you populating and saving the entities?

Comment: so, i have tried creating the databases in the database window on intellij and mysql and populating them in the console but neither way seemed to work. What is supposed to happen is that a user complete the signup process and and the username and password should go to the database but it doesnt work. I tried creating a sql file in my resources folder to create and insert test data, which does work, but any user data that should be stored is lost. I am confused on whether or not i need to pre-create these tables, or if the entity creates the table.

Comment: if i am supposed to be creating the table manually, then i must be using the wrong data types or foreign keys. I also have a UserDetailService if you want to see that one. I have a github repository with all the code if that makes it easier on you....thank you so much for answering

Comment: https://github.com/srimel1/CAPEC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the problem with the code now. You should remove this from your *application.properties*

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

And add `@Transactional` annotation to your *CustomUserDetailService*:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);  
    if(user != null) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    } else {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("username not found");
    }
}
```

If you are testing with embedded (in-memory) databases like *hsqldb* or *h2*, then Spring will create the database tables for you automatically. For other databases, like mySql or PostgreSql, you will have to explicitly instruct Hibernate (via Spring) to create or update the schema objects. This is done by adding this property to your application.properties: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`.

As for associating users with roles, yes, you have to do this either through manual inserts or create an administrative dashboard in your application that manages users and roles. (typical in enterprise applications)

In this particular case, Hibernate will create three tables, called **user**, **role**, and **users_roles**. The last one is to associate users with roles because of the `ManyToMany` association.

Your code is already populating user during the sign-in process, you then have to somehow grant appropriate roles to each user, either via admin dashboard that I mentioned, or insert manually.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this does help a lot thank you. Unfortunately I still cannot figure out what is wrong with my code and why it does not seem that users are being added to my sql database when I signup. I am wondering if it is maybe something wrong with my html? I cannot find the issue and i have been working on this for weeks now.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully, that solves it for you.

Comment: That did it! You are amazing!

Comment: I am happy it worked. The reason you were getting the exception is because your database transaction was demarcated late in the execution path, and you tried to access the related entities when the session was closed and the transaction was completed. By adding the @Transactional in the method where you access the parent entity (User) and the associated entities (Roles), your session stays open and you are then able to fetch the related entities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could possible work. Let me start with some general thoughts on how to model your program and database.

First of all it is important to create your database and model the tables and everything that goes with it. Consider what you want to store in your database in what kind of datatypes and how they are related. Only when your database model is completely set up then try to model your java objects according to your database. This also means that you have to create all the tables before trying to store the data.

So you must have two tables which look like this

User:

```
id         bigint    not null    autoincrement
email      varchar   not null
password   varchar   not null
fullname   varchar   not null
enabled    boolean   not null    default false
```

Role:

```
id         bigint    not null    autoincrement
role       varchar   not null
```

The point here is that you can't store any relationship between the user and the roles he has. In your classes you've modelled a manytomany relationship but the database can't store this.

My solution to this problem is a third table which look like this

UserRoles:

```
id         bigint    not null    autonincrement
userid     bigint    not null
roleid     bigint    not null
```

Of course this table have to have the two foreign key constraints.
With this in mind your classes could look like this:

User:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="user")
  public class User implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="fullname")
  private String fullname;

  @Column(name="password")
  private String password;

  @Column(name="enabled")
  private Boolean enabled;

  @Column(name="email")
  private String email;

  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="userid", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
  private List<UserRoles> roles = null;

  // Gettes & Setters etc.

}
```

Role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")    
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;

  @JsonBackReference
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="roleid")
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
  private List<UserRoles> users;

  // Getters & Setters

}
```

UserRole:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userrole")
public class UserRoles implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;

  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
  private User userid;

  @JsonManagedReference
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
  private UserRole roleid;

  // Getters & Setters

}
```

Of course I skipped some parts in the classes but the modelling works that way. You have now a place where the relationships are stored in your database and you've modelled this in your programm. 
Check and set the JSON settings and fetching strategies according to your needs.